# asp.net - Update db from input and button inside a table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know this seems stupid but I can't find a way to make it work...
I generate a table from a db with this loop  (simplified)

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Approvals)
{
 <tr>
 <td>@item.ApprovalReviewer</td>
 .
 .    
 .     
 . 
 <td>                           
 <button asp-action="Approve" asp-route-id="@item.Key" asp-controller="Dashboard">Approve
 </button>
 </td>
 <td><input asp-for="Approval.ChangeReviewer" value="@item.ChangeReviewer"/></td>                                         
 }
```

it looks like this, I can add a row and delete one, no issue there everything is working

[image]

so basically you enter a name in the reviewer input and when you press approve then that name is updated for the correct key. The issue I have is that I can't find a way to bind that input to the button.

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Approve(int? key, Global obj)
    {       
        var objToApprove = _db.ApprovalTable.Find(key);

        objToApprove.ChangeApproved = true;
        objToApprove.ChangeApprovalDate = DateTime.Now;
        objToApprove.ChangeReviewer = obj.Approval.ChangeReviewer;
        objToApprove.ChangeSigned = obj.Approval.ChangeReviewer;
        _db.ApprovalTable.Update(objToApprove);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        
        return Redirect(Url.Action("ECR", new { id = obj.Approval.ECRNumber }) + "#2"); //TAB #2 FORM APPROVAL 
    }
```

what I need is the value of the input on the same row as the button... sounds easy...I guess not for me..

Comment: How are you submitting this? Normal HTML form submit? JavaScript? How is your form structured?

Comment: Yes just a basic <form method="post">.......</form>

Comment: The details matter. What is in the form? How many forms do you have? Please update your question to be a [mcve].

Comment: I understand but I tried to make it simple to read, many times I see post where 95% of the code is irrelevant to the question. to add to the question, if I take that <input asp-for="Approval.ChangeReviewer"/> outside of the table (loop) everything is working as expected I enter a name click update and the table return the correct name. it is just when that input is inside the loop. i guess I have to give it an index but I don't know how.

Comment: If you follow the instructions on the [mcve] page, you'll see that it clearly defines what should and shouldn't be in the code that you provide in your question. You haven't provided enough here that we can help correct the problem. We theoretically could  write code that would meet your requirements, but we're not a code writing service. We solve problems with existing code. So help us to help you: read over the MCVE directions and come up with an example that fully demonstrates how this should work. If the code isn't necessary, don't include it. If it's necessary, include it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right way of doing it but I was able to solve my problem like this:

I replaced the Foreach loop to a regular loop so that each control would have its own index. Then I passed to the controller the index i so I could get the correct value in the controller.

So it looks like this:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Approvals.Count() - 1; i++)
 {
```

The button where I pass the index i to the controller

```
<button class="---" asp-action="Approve" asp-route-key="@Model.Approvals[i].Key" asp-route-index="@i" asp-route-ecr="@Model.Approvals[i].ECRNumber" asp-controller="Dashboard">Approve</button>
```

and finally the controller where I can retrieve the variable

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Approve(int? key, Global obj, int? ecr, int index)
    {       
        var objToApprove = _db.ApprovalTable.Find(key);

        objToApprove.ChangeApproved = true;
        objToApprove.ChangeApprovalDate = DateTime.Now;
        objToApprove.ChangeReviewer = obj.Approvals[index].ChangeReviewer;
        objToApprove.ChangeSigned = obj.Approvals[index].ChangeReviewer;
        _db.ApprovalTable.Update(objToApprove);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        
        return Redirect(Url.Action("ECR", new { id = ecr }) + "#2");  
    }
```

I have 2 weeks of experience in asp.net so it is hard to know if there is a much better and elegant way of doing this but it works. So it seems that after all I was not there for a "code writing service"...